# How to make a textbox stretch to its parent window's width in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, width, stretch

I have a `TextBox` which I would like to have stretch to its parent's `Width`.

I tried anchoring Top, Left, Right but that only goes just over about 60%, any ideas?

Comment: Make it the same width as the parent in the designer, then anchor it to the right.

Comment: What are you using? WinForms? ASP.NET? WPF? Something else?

Answer (score 8):

As Hans Passant said in a comment, but anchor to the left as well.

Or, if you want to do it programmatically:

```
textBox1.Width = textBox1.Parent.Width;
textBox1.Location = new Point(0,textBox1.Location.Y);
textBox1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right;
```

Answer (score 0):

In WPF use Binding on the property `ActualWidth` of the parent control (in this case its named Container):

```
Width="{Binding Container, Path=ActualWidth}"
```

Another possibility is this (if you don't have named your control and just want to bind to the parent control):

```
Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ActualWidth}"
```

Comment: He is talking about WinForms (he mentioned trying to anchor which is a WinForms only term).

Comment: Oh, ok.. don't know well about winforms and he didn't said for which it is, winforms or wpf.

Answer (score -2):

In Windows Store, Windows Phone 8.0 and 8.1, WPF and all XAML based UI platforms it's possible to use properties

```
VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
```